# How to create a ldap BIND_DN for samba active directory

Tags: python, django, active-directory, ldap, samba

I am trying to setup samba active directory users authentication for my Django app.
I working in linux. I don't have access to windows active directory.
I got a docker image smblds for samba AD DC on Ubuntu 22.04 using

```
docker run --name smblds \
           --publish 389:389 \
           --publish 636:636 \
           --detach smblds/smblds:latest
```

The docker started fine. I can see the smb.conf and other tdb files created.

But this docker does not set the BIND_DN value.
So, I executed the docker and from inside the smblds docker I provisioned the active directory with

```
samba-tool domain provision --use-rfc2307 --interactive
```

I used all the default settings for Realm, Domain, server role, dns backend and Administrator password
I see following messages in the output

```
Setting up self join
Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=ms-WMI-StringSetParam,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=samdom,DC=example,DC=com)
Repack: re-packed 10000 records so far
Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=server-Display,CN=409,CN=DisplaySpecifiers,CN=Configuration,DC=samdom,DC=example,DC=com)
Repacking database from v1 to v2 format (first record CN=51cba88b-99cf-4e16-bef2-c427b38d0767,CN=Operations,CN=DomainUpdates,CN=System,DC=samdom,DC=example,DC=com)
```

Is any of these a BIND_DN.
Actually when I try to connect to active directory using python ldap I see invalid credential error.

```
>>> import ldap
>>> ldap_server = ldap.initialize("ldap://172.17.0.5/")
>>> ldap_server.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT, ldap.OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW)
>>> ldap_server.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEWCTX, 0)
>>> ldap_server.start_tls_s()
>>> ldap_server.simple_bind_s("CN=ms-WMI-StringSetParam,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=samdom,DC=example,DC=com", "Passw0rd")
```

ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS: {'msgtype': 97, 'msgid': 3, 'result': 49, 'desc': 'Invalid credentials', 'ctrls': [], 'info': '80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1'}

I know I set the password during provisioning.
But what is the initial BIND_DN that I can use to bind with the samba active directory in the ldap_server.simple_bind_s call?

Basically is there any BIND_DN created for the samba active directory like it is for openLDAP?
If not how do I connect to samba active directory?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Bind DNs" are **DNs that represent user accounts.** This works in Active Directory the same as in other LDAP services.

The standard user account that exists in fresh AD installations – certain to be the one that you've set a password for – is **`Administrator`** which is placed in the default `Users` container; its DN might therefore be **`CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com`**.

As a special case, Active Directory DCs (including Samba) allow you to directly specify a non-DN username in the "bind DN" field (either in the AD UPN `user@domain.tld` format or in the NT4 `DOMAIN\user` format), so you should also be able to bind as `Administrator@ad.example.com`.

You could also bypass the procedure using a Kerberos (GSSAPI or GSS-SPNEGO) bind instead of a plaintext password. In a full AD environment (i.e. properly configured DNS) you would be able to `kinit` as `Administrator@AD.EXAMPLE.COM` and invoke `.sasl_gssapi_bind_s()`<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> (More precisely it should be `.sasl_non_interactive_bind_s("GSS-SPNEGO")` for AD.)

Comment: By default it's `CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=samdom,DC=example,DC=com` except `REALM` is overwritten.